# How i can prevent people from using my stream link, Azure media services

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-cdn

i have tried many times but i di not find good working method
Please help to solve this out
My channel is running and live, i can preview the stream

How i can get to this example link: 'https://XXXXXXX.azureedge.net/QualityLevels(2200000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl-v3,audiotrack=audio).m3u8',
 height: "100%",

So i can only allow my domain name to embed the sream link

Thank you...

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a solution like CORS configuration on the streaming Origin server?  Or CORS configuration at the CDN delivery level?
I'm not sure about the CDN capabilities for that, but i know that the Azure Media Services Streaming Endpoint does not yet have CORS configuration support. It's on our backlog.

Answer (score 0):

**Control content access**

You can control who has access to your content by configuring the content key policy. Media Services supports multiple ways of authenticating users who make key requests. You must configure the content key policy. The client (player) must meet the policy before the key can be delivered to the client. The content key policy can have open or token restriction.

Full documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/content-protection-overview

Comment: Hi not helping because i wanna creat it with azure CDN for example : 'https://XXXXXXX.azureedge.net/QualityLevels(2200000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl-v3,audiotrack=audio).m3u8'

Comment: I wanna know how to creat distrubtion with azure cdn for my live streaming .

Comment: THE XXXXXXX any name i chose .

Comment: Have you looked at the CDN documentation then?  You can use the Rules Engine to match the referring domain or a URL match condition.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-rules-engine-reference-match-conditions

Comment: I was meaning how to create distribution for my live streaming
This my stream link :https://amsaccounter90-euno.streaming.media.azure.net/0a3230bf-8s1e-4cfc-afe3-2072b9d77479/dcj1jka9-f63f-4d06-8b14-9ue5413eu62e.ism/manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl-v3,audiotrack=audio).m3u8
wish i want to make integration with azureedge.net CDN
Is there any specific documentation for that task?

Comment: Hey, do you have Skype supoort? please i can explain more there